# Bootstrap 3 make navbar always collapse, disable breakpoint

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want the bootstrap navbar to always be collapsed. 
I used customize and under '@grid-float-breakpoint' i tried to put - 0, but it didn't work.
I tried this solution - http://www.bootply.com/jXxt4Dc54A

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
   display: none!important;
}
```

but this prevent from the menu to be shown

While i'm asking.. what is the best way to style the navbar if i want on one page to collapse at 768px and a different page not to collapse at all?

Comment: That was asked recently, http://www.bootply.com/114896

Comment: That one was effed, better: http://www.bootply.com/122826